# Wrong User when posting Open Graph Actions

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Maybe this is just how unapproved actions work (we're still testing)...

I have gone through the process of setting up a new action, wired up my code base to have the appropriate meta tags and what not, and have the post working. When i test action, I see it show up in my activity log, and other devs on the app see it show up in their timelines. Perfect!

However, if one of the other devs on the app posts an action, it shows up as if I did it. It shows in my activity log as me, and shows in their timeline as if i had trigger the action.

As far as I know, we're not passing user info along with the request. Just the object data.

Am I missing something obvious? Is this just how unapproved actions work?

Comment: As I have used open graph the user is not passed anyway. FB gets if through the security (cookies and all that stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound silly, but when you're making the post to Facebook make sure you're passing the ***user's*** authentication token and not your own, otherwise all actions anyone else does will posted as you.

Comment: #facepalm - this was the issue. In the "Get Code" bits, I thought the access_token was related to the action, not the user, so I was passing the same token for all users. Thanks!